# Guardar dato tipeado en input en un solo excel

Tags: javascript

tengo un código que me genera un excel que me guarda lo que se tipea en un input, pasa que me va generando un excel para cada búsqueda, y lo que quiero es que me genere un mismo excel con todo lo que busque en el input y guarde, acá dejo el código, agradecería su ayuda... Gracias

```
var valores = \[\]; 
var inputValue = document.getElementById('categories').value;
if (inputValue.trim() !== '') {
valores.push({ Data: inputValue });

      
      var workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      var worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(valores);
    
    
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Datos');   
      
      var excelBuffer = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
      saveExcelFile(excelBuffer, 'datos.xlsx');
    
      document.getElementById('categories').value = '';
    }

function saveExcelFile(buffer, fileName) {
var blob = new Blob(\[buffer\], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```